# Failed to create the VirtualBoxClient COM object. The application will now terminate. Callee RC: NS_ERROR_FACTORY_NOT_REGISTERED (0x80040154)

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, kali-linux

[image]

I'm not able to start the virtualbox when I try to open the virtalbox I got this Error message
I need help on this

Comment: Is the client machine a 64-bit machine?  And is Hardware Virtualization set ON in the BIOS?

Comment: [Enable SIP](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=100762). If that doesn’t work you will have to give us more details

Comment: Yes it is 64 bit

Comment: Let me check once again in the BIOS. I already turn on the virtualization. anyways i'm gonna check again

Comment: I checked Vitrualization tech is enable

Comment: You likely restarted your system when checking BIOS.  Try reinstalling Virtual Box ad restarting again.

Comment: Okay lets try that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article
[Fedora virtualbox RC: NS_ERROR_FACTORY_NOT_REGISTERED](https://www.unixmen.com/fedora-virtualbox-rc-nserrorfactorynotregistered/)
advises the following actions:

```
yum  install  dkms
find /usr/lib/virtualbox -maxdepth 1 -name '*.so' -exec ln -s {} /usr/lib/virtualbox/components/
chown root.root /tmp
chmod ug-s /tmp
chmod 1777 /tmp
```

---

A very similar bug-report, although old one, is
[OSE / Hardened: NS_ERROR_FACTORY_NOT_REGISTERED => Fix symlinks](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/3672#comment:28).

The solution here is to add the following symlinks:

```
cd /usr/lib64/virtualbox/component
ln -s ../VBoxDDU.so .
ln -s ../VBoxREM.so .
ln -s ../VBoxRT.so .
ln -s ../VBoxVMM.so .
ln -s ../VBoxXPCOM.so .
```

Then restart VirtualBox.

If I understood right the comments, the problem arises when the `bin/` directory
was moved.